# BufferedReader is unable to read last line in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In my code I take input from console and read from it like this:

`InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(System.in);`
`BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(sc);`

But when I am not able to read last line of input?

For Example:
If I want to read c and console input is shown below,

it is not getting when there is nothing after c

a
b
c(EOF)

but for input console like this where after c one line is there it is possible to read c

a
b
c
(EOF)

Actual code:

```
        InputStreamReader sc = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(sc);
        String s = bufRead.readLine();
        int t = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int k = 0; // no. of city

        for (int l = 0; l < t; l++) {
            s = bufRead.readLine();
            k = Integer.parseInt(s);
            cityDetails = new String[3][k];

            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                s = bufRead.readLine();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                cityDetails[0][j] = st.nextToken();
                cityDetails[1][j] = st.nextToken();
                cityDetails[2][j] = st.nextToken();
            }
            s = bufRead.readLine();
            dist = Double.parseDouble(s);
             System.out.println(dist);

}
```

Comment: You aren't reading anything there. Post all the relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: A 'line' in `BufferedReader` is terminated by `\n`. In other words, ENTER key. If you write `a [ENTER] b [ENTER] c [ENTER]` then those are three lines. =)

Comment: @LittleChild : correct but is there any way i can append `[ENTER]` at the end of `system.in` because I am not giving input it is given by system so I can't add `[ENTER]` there

Comment: @user2908533 `System.in` is an `InputStream` object =) You cannot append `ENTER` to that

Comment: @utdemir : I have add my actual code can you check it

Comment: @LittleChild : Is there any other way for this?

Comment: @user2908533 Please read the answer I posted underneath the comments. Use a `Scanner`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read till `BufferedReader` does not return null. It needs to be in a loop.
Here is an example by Mykong

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ignore the file part. What matters is how to read using a `BufferedReader`. It stays the same for keyboard input and file.

Alternatively, you can use a `java.util.Scanner` which has methods to read different types of primitive data.

Comment: previously I was using scanner only but it was having same problem